# Hide another component on the click of radio button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm very new to React. I'm building a flight booking website. I want to hide the return date form field when the user selects one way trip. I wanted to know what is the best way to go about it.

```
const TripTypeButton = (props) => {
    const [rSelected, setRSelected] = useState(null);
      
    return (
      <div>
        <ButtonGroup>
          <Button color="primary" onClick={() => setRSelected(1)} active={rSelected === 1}>Round Trip</Button>
          <Button color="secondary" onClick={() => setRSelected(2)} active={rSelected === 2}>One Way</Button>
        </ButtonGroup>
      </div>
    );
  }

const HomePage = (props) =>{
    return(
    <div>
        <div>
            <h2> Search for flights</h2>
        </div>
        <div>
            <Form>
                <Row form>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <TripTypeButton />
                    </FormGroup>
                </Row>
                <Row form>
                  <Col md={3}>
                    <FormGroup>
                      <Label>Departure</Label>
                      <Input type="date" id="departure"  name="departure"/>
                    </FormGroup>
                  </Col>
                  <Col md={3}>
                    <FormGroup>
                      <Label for="exampleState">Return</Label>
                      <Input type="date" name="return" id="return"/>
                    </FormGroup>
                  </Col>
              <Row/>
            </Form>
        </div>
    </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: maintatin the radiobutton state in HomePage(parent component), pass the rSelected, setRSelected as props to TripTypeButton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for this situation, you need to keep the state of selected trip type in `HomePage` component and then based on that state render the `Return flight` or not!

like below:

```
const HomePage = (props) => {
   
   const [rSelected, setRSelected] = useState(null);



   return (

      // some code 


      // trip type button handler
      <TripTypeButton handleSelectedTripType={setRSelected} rSelected={rSelected} />


      // the button section of code 
      { rSelected !== 1 
        && <Col md={3}>
             <FormGroup>
               <Label for="exampleState">Return</Label>
               <Input type="date" name="return" id="return"/>
             </FormGroup>
           </Col> 
       }


      // rest of jsx code

   )
   
}
```

and your `TripTypeButton` would be like below:

```
const TripTypeButton = ({ handleSelectedTripType, rSelected }) => {
      
    return (
      <div>
        <ButtonGroup>
          <Button color="primary" onClick={() => handleSelectedTripType(1)} active={rSelected === 1}>Round Trip</Button>
          <Button color="secondary" onClick={() => handleSelectedTripType(2)} active={rSelected === 2}>One Way</Button>
        </ButtonGroup>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

this is called lifting state up in React! and by that you keep your state in top level components and manage data manipulation by passing required handlers down to the child components by directly props or context!

Comment: Thanks! this worked. If I were to convert HomePage to a class what changes would I need to make?

Comment: you need to convert it syntactically and use the constructor() function of class to define your `rSelected ` state and access it inside your component via `this.rSelected `  syntax, also make sure that you have a render method and return the jsx part inside of that